# Ruby - EM::connection send_data not sending data

Tags: ruby, tcp, eventmachine

I have a class that is extending EM::Connection. Inside that class, I check for new entries in a database, if there is a new entry, I format the data and send it across a tcp connection using send_data. After sending the data, it logs that it has done so to a text file, then updates the database to mark the record as sent.

This program runs indefinitely and sends the tcp updates at frequencies driven by sporadic user based activity that generates the database records.

Normally, I can watch the data pass across the network using the linux ngrep command.

I am currently having a problem where the send_data command is not sending the data and not throwing any errors. After it gets in this state, it will not send any more data until I restart the program. What makes the issue worse is that because send_data does not throw any errors when this occurs, the program writes logs as if it worked and then updates the database record and marks it as sent.

Is there any way to check the results of the send_data command?

If this is related to the far end not reading and the read buffer maxing out, is there anyway that I can check my outbound buffer size?

Comment: Can you expand on your question? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Calling send_data from a different thread (like an EM.defer code block and not callback block could cause this)